# How to convert existing macOS command line tool (for a launch daemon) into a bundled app for code signing & stapling?

Tags: xcode, daemon, app-bundle, notarize, launch-daemon

I have a macOS command line tool project for my launch daemon (written in C++). It compiles into a single Mach-O binary file.

I need to code sign and [notarize it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution?language=objc) for distribution (outside of the App Store.) For that, it seems like I need to convert it into an app-bundle like structure. (That is needed so that I can [staple the notarization ticket](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow#3087720) to it.)

I found [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/signing-a-daemon-with-a-restricted-entitlement#Create-a-minimal-daemon-project) that describes how to do it from the start by creating a new project as a macOS app.

But in my case I already have an existing macOS project, created as a "command line tool". How do I convert it to build into an app-bundle in Xcode?

Comment: Just to add some info to the answer that was deleted by @pmdj. No, the stapler tool will not "staple" the ticket to a Mach-O binary. It will give this error: `The staple and validate action failed! Error 73.` This happens because it tries to update the `Contents/CodeResources` file "inside" the mach-o binary, thinking that what you're stapling is an .app bundle. Silly, I know. But that's the way they coded it.

Comment: Yup, I checked our build script and we just don't staple the daemon binary. (Stapling isn't strictly required, but I think will cause the process to fail if the executable is run for the first time without an internet connection.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can notarize and staple if you put your binary into an installer PKG.